# A class has divided 6 students randomly into teams A and B. What is the probability that 3 students from team A will come first, second and third?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

My take on the problem is, considering the players to be indistinguishable individually other than by their teams i.e. the players are A,B,A,B,A,B. They can be arranged in $\frac{6!}{3!3!}$ ways.
Assuming the arrangement of 3 players of team A becoming 1st, 2nd, 3rd to be AAABBB, this arrangement can be only done in 1 way the answer to the question comes out to be
$$\frac{1}{\frac{6!}{3!3!}}= \frac{3!3!}{6!}$$.
but the options given for this question are

a) $\frac{3!}{6!}$

b) $\frac{1}{6!}$

c) $\frac{3!2}{6!}$

d) $\frac{3}{6!}$

Help me understand where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Your answer is the correct one in my opinion given the way the question is worded.

Answer (score 3):

The probability that the first student that walks in will be from team A is: $\frac{3}{6}$

Given that the first student to walk in was from team A, the probability that the second student that walks in will be from team A is: $\frac{2}{5}$

Given that the first two students to walk in were from team A, the probability that the third student that walks in will be from team A is: $\frac{1}{4}$

The multiplication rule then gives us that the probability that the first three students to walk in will all be from team A is:
$$(\frac{3}{6})(\frac{2}{5})(\frac{1}{4})=\frac{3!3!}{6!}$$

Answer (score 0):

Combinatorially:
There are ${6\choose 3}=20$ ways to choose the top three from the 6 students.  There is 1 way that all three of the top three can come from group A.

The probability then is $\frac{1}{20}$=0.05.

Answer (score -1):

I was thinking of the case where all the players are distinguishable : $A_1,A_2,A_3,B_1,B_2,B_3$ then we need to find the probability of the arrangement $AAAB_iB_jB_k$. Number of such cases are $3!$ and the total number of arrangements of $A_1,A_2,A_3,B_1,B_2,B_3$ are $6!$.

So the required probability becomes $\frac{3!}{6!}$.

Although I'm unsure whether this is the right wat to go about the problem.

Comment: Your numerator and denominator need to both be consistent with what you are or are not treating as distinguishable/indistinguishable.  Your numerator of $3!$ was where the $A$'s were all indistinguishable.  It should have been $3!\cdot 3!$ for the numerator if the $A$'s are distinguishable as they are for your denominator with the $6!$.  Otherwise your denominator would have needed to change to have $A$'s indistinguishable as well which would have yielded a final answer of $\dfrac{3!}{\binom{6}{3}3!}$ which is of course equal to the answer found elsewhere of $\dfrac{3!3!}{6!}$